# Am I getting the benefits of async and await in the following code

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I have the following code in which I am using an async keyword in my GroupBy clause, however I am told by intellisence that this call is not awaited and will run synchronously, my question is would my two calls to `GetAllLanguages` and `GetAllStores` and my subsequent call to `Task.WaitAll(languagesTask, storesTask);` use async features or would all my code run synchronously since I am not awaiting the GroupBy statement. also is it possible to await the `.GroupBy(async resourceApplicationType ..` call.

```
 public async Task UpdateAllResources()
        {
            var applicationTypes = databaseSettings.Select(dbcs => dbcs.ResourceApplicationType);
            var commandsPerApplication = applicationTypes
                .GroupBy(async resourceApplicationType =>
                {
                    var languagesTask = GetAllLanguages(resourceApplicationType);
                    var storesTask = GetAllStores(resourceApplicationType);
                    var resourceCategory = ResourceApplicationToCategoriesMapper.Map(resourceApplicationType);
                    Task.WaitAll(languagesTask, storesTask);
                    var commands = from category in resourceCategory
                            from language in languagesTask.Result
                            from store in storesTask.Result
                            select new UpdateResourcesCommand
                            {
                                ApplicationType = resourceApplicationType,
                                StoreCode = store.Code,
                                LocaleCode = language.Locale,
                                ResourceCategory = category
                            };
                    return new
                    {
                        applicationType = resourceApplicationType, commands
                    };
                });

           commandsPerApplication.ForEach(commandsGroup =>
           {
               commandsGroup.Key.Result.commands.ForEach(async command =>
               {
                   await commandExecutor.Execute<UpdateResourcesCommand, Task>(command);
               });
           });
        }

        private Task<IEnumerable<Language>> GetAllLanguages(ResourceApplication applicationType)
        {
            return allLanguagesQueryRetriever.GetByComponentName(InstanceName.GetUniqueName<IAllLanguagesQuery>(applicationType.ToString()))
                .Execute(new AllLanguagesCriteria());
        }

        private Task<IEnumerable<Store>> GetAllStores(ResourceApplication applicationType)
        {
            return allStoresQueryRetriever
                .GetByComponentName(InstanceName.GetUniqueName<IAllStoresQuery>(applicationType.ToString()))
                .Execute(new AllStoresCriteria());
        }
```

Comment: You're not awaiting `Task.WaitAll(languagesTask, storesTask);`  in your `UpdateAllResources` function. Which could mean that the task hasn't finished before you try to access the result

Comment: @JLevett that statement is not awaitable "Type void is not awaitable", it essentially does the awaiting.

Comment: My apologies. You could also use `await Task.WhenAll()`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the **Threads** window *Debug-> Windows-> Threads* show ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic rule of thumb is "Without an await, async will run synchronously".

You could easily get your `GroupBy()` to run properly `async` by exchanging `Task.WaitAll()` for `await Task.WhenAll()`.

Comment: I am still required to acess the Result object `commandsGroup.Key.Result.commands.ForEach(async command =>` after using WhenAll, is this ok? I would have thought if I did await everything then I could just bypass calling Result?!

Comment: Unfortunately not, that only works if you await individual tasks and assign their results directly to a variable, e.g. `var languages = await GetAllLanguages()`